# Does anyone know how to use multiple interface's port declare?

Tags: system-verilog

Now, I'm trying to study about systemverilog from here.
the following internet site what i have learn.

http://www.testbench.in/SL_04_PHASE_1_TOP.html

from here, I am so confused the usage of output_intf in

`testcase TC (mem_intf,input_intf,output_intf);`

I mean that I think it should be

`testcase TC (mem_intf,input_intf,output_intf[4]);`

why not the output_intf[4] ?

How do I understand this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because output_intf[4] would mean to connect interface instance number 4 (which does not exist) to the testcase port. You want to pass the entire array of instance to the port.